# Aggregate function in update query with case statement in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to write update query by using aggregate function and case statement.
Some how i am stuck

Initially i have written following query which gave me error tha,"Aggregate function can not be used in update statement

```
UPDATE report
SET report.LoadDischargeQty = 
CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(CRG_ArrDep,1,1) = 'D' AND cargo.CRG_Quantity is NOT NULL THEN cargo.CRG_Quantity 
 ELSE
     CASE WHEN report.PlaId = 'LP' THEN 
                                    CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(CRG_ArrDep,1,1) = 'D' THEN ISNULL(SUM(CRG_SFgrMT),0) END -  
                                    CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(CRG_ArrDep,1,1) = 'A' THEN ISNULL(SUM(CRG_SFgrMT),0)END 
         WHEN report.PlaId = 'DP' THEN 
                                    CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(CRG_ArrDep,1,1) = 'A' THEN ISNULL(SUM(CRG_SFgrMT),0) END-
                                    CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(CRG_ArrDep,1,1) = 'D' THEN ISNULL(SUM(CRG_SFgrMT),0)END
        ELSE 0 END  
END 
from #CargoPerformanceReport report
INNER JOIN POSCARGO cargo ON cargo.POS_ID = report.PositionId AND ISNULL(cargo.CRG_Deleted,0)=0
```

So I refactored it as follow

```
UPDATE report
SET report.LoadDischargeQty = 
CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(CRG_ArrDep,1,1) = 'D' AND cargo.CRG_Quantity is NOT NULL THEN cargo.CRG_Quantity 
 ELSE
    select quantity.dischargeQuantity from (SELECT CASE WHEN report.PlaId = 'LP' THEN 
                                    CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(CRG_ArrDep,1,1) = 'D' THEN ISNULL(SUM(CRG_SFgrMT),0) END -  
                                    CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(CRG_ArrDep,1,1) = 'A' THEN ISNULL(SUM(CRG_SFgrMT),0)END 
         WHEN report.PlaId = 'DP' THEN 
                                    CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(CRG_ArrDep,1,1) = 'A' THEN ISNULL(SUM(CRG_SFgrMT),0) END-
                                    CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(CRG_ArrDep,1,1) = 'D' THEN ISNULL(SUM(CRG_SFgrMT),0)END
        ELSE 0 END  dischargeQuantity ) quantity
END 
from #CargoPerformanceReport report
INNER JOIN POSCARGO cargo ON cargo.POS_ID = report.PositionId AND ISNULL(cargo.CRG_Deleted,0)=0
```

table structure

```
CREATE TABLE #CargoPerformanceReport
(
    PositionId              VARCHAR(12),
    PortAndActivityName     VARCHAR(100),
    PlaId                   VARCHAR(12),
    LoadDischargeQty            REAL,

);
```

Insert into #CargoPerformanceReport
Values('100',null,'LP',null)

```
CREATE TABLE #Poscargo
(
    POS_ID              VARCHAR(12),
    CRG_ArrDep          VARCHAR(3),
    CRG_SFgrMT          REAL,
    CRG_Quantity        REAL,
    CRG_Deleted         BIT
);


Insert Into #Poscargo(POS_ID,CRG_ArrDep,CRG_SFgrMT,null,0)
Values ('100','DD',100)

Insert Into #Poscargo(POS_ID,CRG_ArrDep,CRG_SFgrMT)
Values ('100','AD',100)

Insert Into #Poscargo(POS_ID,CRG_ArrDep,CRG_SFgrMT)
Values ('100','DD',200)

Insert Into #Poscargo(POS_ID,CRG_ArrDep,CRG_SFgrMT)
Values ('100','AD',50)


Insert Into #Poscargo(POS_ID,CRG_ArrDep,CRG_SFgrMT)
Values ('101','DL',200)


Insert Into #Poscargo(POS_ID,CRG_ArrDep,CRG_SFgrMT)
Values ('101','AL',200)

SELECT * FROM #Poscargo
SELECT * FROM #CargoPerformanceReport
```

result:-

```
PositionId |    PlaId | LoadDischargeQty
100        |     LP   | 150
```

but it is not right way and also has error.

anyone have optimized solution for the same?

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result? that really help

Comment: Provide format instead of image thanks

Comment: I updated the question,now you can check

Comment: Where are `CRG_Quantity` and `CRG_Deleted` columns in your sample data?

Comment: I removed my answer after a deeper look at your code. What is this supposed to mean: `CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(CRG_ArrDep,1,1) = 'D' THEN ISNULL(CRG_SFgrMT,0) END -  
                                        CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(CRG_ArrDep,1,1) = 'A' THEN ISNULL(CRG_SFgrMT,0) END `? Did you mean `CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(CRG_ArrDep,1,1) = 'D' THEN ISNULL(CRG_SFgrMT,0)  
WHEN SUBSTRING(CRG_ArrDep,1,1) = 'A' THEN -ISNULL(CRG_SFgrMT,0) END `?

Comment: yes,i tried this but it was giving me error,I might miss something

Comment: In your code prototype why `cargo.CRG_Quantity` is not treated as `CRG_SFgrMT`? Is it supposed to be used instead of aggregating `SUM(CRG_SFgrMT)` or as a regular row, so it has to be inside `SUM()` as well?

Answer (score 1):

Put all that stuff into subquery:

```
SELECT LoadDischargeQty = 
  CASE 
    WHEN report.PlaId = 'LP' 
    THEN 1 
    ELSE -1 
  END * cargo.qty
FROM CargoPerformanceReport report
CROSS APPLY(
  SELECT SUM(
    CASE 
      WHEN CRG_ArrDep LIKE 'D%' 
      THEN 1 
      WHEN CRG_ArrDep LIKE 'A%' 
      THEN -1 
      ELSE 0
    END * ISNULL(CRG_SFgrMT, 0)
    ) qty
  FROM POSCARGO cargo
  WHERE cargo.POS_ID = report.PositionId 
    AND ISNULL(cargo.CRG_Deleted,0)=0
) cargo
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/648d0/7

I don't understand how is `CRG_Quantity` column supposed to be used and you did not provide any row with that data so I removed it to show you the aggregation itself. Works fine, you'll get your 150. You may easily convert it into `update` statement.

Comment: No sir,It is not my requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps something like this?
It uses cases with summed cases.

Test on SQL Fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/6808d8/1/1)

```
UPDATE t
SET LoadDischargeQty = q.CalcDischargeQty
FROM #CargoPerformanceReport t
JOIN
(
    SELECT report.PositionId, report.PlaId,
    CASE 
    WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN LEFT(cargo.CRG_ArrDep,1) = 'D' THEN cargo.CRG_Quantity END) IS NOT NULL 
    THEN SUM(CASE WHEN LEFT(cargo.CRG_ArrDep,1) = 'D' THEN cargo.CRG_Quantity END)
    ELSE CASE 
         WHEN report.PlaId = 'LP' 
         THEN SUM(CASE WHEN LEFT(cargo.CRG_ArrDep,1) = 'D' THEN cargo.CRG_SFgrMT END) -  
              SUM(CASE WHEN LEFT(cargo.CRG_ArrDep,1) = 'A' THEN cargo.CRG_SFgrMT END) 
         WHEN report.PlaId = 'DP' 
         THEN SUM(CASE WHEN LEFT(cargo.CRG_ArrDep,1) = 'A' THEN cargo.CRG_SFgrMT END) -  
              SUM(CASE WHEN LEFT(cargo.CRG_ArrDep,1) = 'D' THEN cargo.CRG_SFgrMT END) 
         ELSE 0
         END
    END AS CalcDischargeQty
    FROM #CargoPerformanceReport report
    INNER JOIN #Poscargo cargo 
       ON cargo.POS_ID = report.PositionId AND (cargo.CRG_Deleted = 0 OR cargo.CRG_Deleted IS NULL)
    GROUP BY report.PositionId, report.PlaId
) q ON t.PositionId = q.PositionId;
```

**Sample Data**

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#CargoPerformanceReport') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #CargoPerformanceReport;
CREATE TABLE #CargoPerformanceReport
(
    PositionId          VARCHAR(12) PRIMARY KEY,
    PortAndActivityName VARCHAR(100),
    PlaId               VARCHAR(12),
    LoadDischargeQty    REAL
);

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Poscargo') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Poscargo;
CREATE TABLE #Poscargo
(
    POS_ID       VARCHAR(12),
    CRG_ArrDep   VARCHAR(3),
    CRG_SFgrMT   REAL,
    CRG_Quantity REAL,
    CRG_Deleted  BIT
);

Insert into #CargoPerformanceReport Values 
('100','name1','LP',null),
('101','name2','DP',null),
('102','name3','DP',null);

Insert Into #Poscargo(POS_ID, CRG_ArrDep, CRG_SFgrMT, CRG_Quantity, CRG_Deleted) Values 
 ('100','DD',100,null,0)
,('100','AD',100,null,0)
,('100','DD',200,null,0)
,('100','AD',50,null,0)
,('101','DL',100,null,0)
,('101','AL',200,null,0)
,('102','DL',100,500,0)
,('102','AL',200,null,0);
```

**Result**

```
PositionId PortAndActivityName PlaId LoadDischargeQty
---------- ------------------- ----- ----------------
100        name1               LP    150
101        name2               DP    100
102        name3               DP    500
```